# Does Twisted cache DNS lookups? Does it honour TTL?

Tags: python, dns, twisted

If I use the Twisted Endpoint API to make a series of connections to the same host, will Twisted cache the DNS lookup between requests?

If it does, will it honour the DNS record's TTL?

My implementation is fairly vanilla. I instantiate a `SSL4ClientEndpoint` with host, port etc, and through the life of the program I use it to make several connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Twisted simply uses the OS' resolver, so the answer to both questions is "as much as your OS does".

Comment: This is correct.  The question *could* have been about `twisted.names`' resolver, but it seems the asker is concerned with the default behavior :).